# ACH transfer to incorrect account type ('Savings' instead of 'Checking') - US bank to another US bank: Is it lost?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, savings-account, checking-account, ach

A friend visiting the US was asked to transfer $2000 for rent payment to a US bank account.

On February 12th, while doing an ACH transfer from his US bank account to the landlord's account in another US bank, he put in the correct Account Number and Routing Number; however, he selected the Account Type as 'Savings Account' instead of the correct 'Checking Account' (the confusion happened because India doesn't have 'Checking' accounts).

The money was deducted from his account immediately; but when the landlord didn't receive it in a few days, my friend contacted his bank, and they opened up an 'investigation' for which they charged $110.

It has been more than a week, and the bank says that the investigation is still 'ongoing' and that they cannot predict when it will conclude.

Due to obvious and expected pressure from the landlord, my friend issued a cheque to him for $2000, thus paying twice.

Have we lost the first payment of $2000 transferred via ACH? If there is any chance of recovering it, instead of paying twice. What else should we try?

[We are requesting guidance, rather than simply waiting on the investigation, because the amount involved is more than twice our combined monthly salaries.]

Is there a faster way to get the $2000 back that never processed?

Comment: the chosen account type should have little or no impact on the success of the transfer. I recommend verifying the remaining numbers / data. Either way, the money _is_ somewhere, so he should be able to get it back.